# OpenCV: Why are my Mat types mismatched for matchTemplate?

Tags: java, opencv

I'm using the Java version of OpenCV. I need to do a matchTemplate operation to find targets within an image. When I run my code, I get an error where an assertion failed, saying imgType == tmptype was false. As a diagnostic operation I ran S.o.p(src.type()); and S.o.p(tmp.type());. I got 16 and 0, respectively. Why did this happen and how can I fix it?

Comment: you are trying to match a color to a grayscale image. don't do that ;)

Comment: Which is which? When I show src in a window it's in color, and tmp is loaded from a file, and the original file is in color. Which one is grayscale in this case? The 16 or 0?

Comment: 0 == gray(CV_8U), 16 == color(CV_8UC3)

Comment: Okay, so my code for this part is greenImage = Highgui.imread("E:/green.png"); S.o.p(greenImage.type()); Why would it be grayscale when the source image (green.png) is in color?

Comment: that *can't* be. imread without a flag *forces* a rgb image, no matter what original content. but you can do `Highgui.imread("E:/green.png", 0);` to force it to return a grayscale

Comment: Well, I'd like to avoid a grayscale, as my program is meant to seek out color. I don't want to force a grayscale. Would saying `Highgui.imread("E:/green.png",16)` force it to load in color?

Comment: 1. no idea if it works with colored images. 2. no, the 0 is CV_IMREAD_GRAYSCALE, i was just too lazy to type it.

Comment: Are you sure it's CV_IMREAD_GRAYSCALE and not CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE?

Comment: sorry, you're right. i was too lazy to *look it up* in the 1st place.